Firebase Cloud Functions Returning 503 Error After Updating Billing Information
I've been using Firebase Cloud Functions with the Blaze plan in my project for some time, primarily as a REST API for a React client (mainly for CRUD operations). Recently, I received emails from Firebase notifying me that my billing information might have expired and needed updating.
Yesterday (Saturday), I updated the billing information, and the update appeared successful. However, today I'm encountering a problem: all my Cloud Functions return a 503 Server Error with the following message:
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <title>503 Server Error</title>
    </head>
    <body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
        <h1>Error: Server Error</h1>
        <h2>The service you requested is not available yet.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.</h2>
    </body>
</html>

I'm wondering if this is a common issue after updating billing info on the Blaze plan. Do I need to wait for some time for the services to reactivate, or is there an additional step I might have missed? Any insights or troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.
I tried fetching data from my Firebase Cloud Function endpoint at https://usersdb-*********q-uc.a.run.app to retrieve user information. This has been working as expected in the past, but after updating my billing information, I now receive a 503 Server Error with the message stating the service is "not available yet."
What I Expected:
I expected the endpoint to return the usual JSON response with user data, as it has done in previous requests. Instead, I'm getting a 503 error page with no additional details.
